# SQL Server Query - select returns rows, but update 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a slight issue in a SQL Server 2016 (Developer Edition) Database that I am trying to learn on. I have a query that when I run a select, it returns rows fine, but when I try and update on similar column structure it returns 0 rows and I cannot work it out and its driving me crazy :(

The following returns results :

```
select DISTINCT R.PersonID, R.CompleteDate, E.ExactTime, U.RunCode
FROM Results R
JOIN Run PR ON PR.ID = R.RunID AND PR.ProgrammeID = 8
JOIN Event E ON E.ID = R.CompleteEventID
JOIN Unit U ON U.ID = R.UnitID
JOIN Batches BN ON R.PersonID = BN.ID
```

But the following updates 0 rows :

```
UPDATE E
SET ExactTime = BN.CorrectTiming
FROM Event E, Results R, Run PR, Unit U, Batches BN
WHERE R.CompleteEventID = E.ID
AND  R.RunID = PR.ID 
AND PR.ProgrammeID = 8
AND R.UnitID = U.ID
AND R.PesonID = BN.ID
AND U.RunCode = BN.RunCode
AND R.CompleteDate = BN.CorrectDate
```

Before I start re-writing again from the ground up, can anyone check my syntax and see if there is anything wrong with that ?

Cheers!

Comment: The two queries do not have identical logic.  Why would you expect them to behave the same?

Comment: Have you tried using the modern `JOIN` syntax you're using in the first query in the second query, rather than switching to a long-outdated syntax?

Comment: Well, it is two different query joins so quite possible that the select returns but the update does not. What happens if you convert the update to a select i.e. change the first two lines UPDATE E SET ExactTime = BN.CorrectTiming to SELECT *

Comment: 2nd statement has `U.RunCode = BN.RunCode` and also `R.CompleteDate = BN.CorrectDate` that the 1st one doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you could provide some data sample.

Maybe try this:

```
UPDATE E
SET E.ExactTime = BN.CorrectTiming
FROM Results R
INNER JOIN Run PR ON PR.ID = R.RunID
AND PR.ProgrammeID = 8
INNER JOIN Event E ON E.ID = R.CompleteEventID
INNER JOIN Unit U ON U.ID = R.UnitID
INNER JOIN Batches BN ON R.PersonID = BN.ID;
```